# Javascript sweetalert plugin always shows an input text box

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, sweetalert

I just started using sweetalert for javascript and don't understand why my alert always shows a input box in the error message.
Heres the code im using:

```
swal("Account Number Error", "Please Enter Account Number", "error");
```

Here is an image:
[image: In the image you can see that it is still holding like a default message in it?]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520569/sweetalert-change-modal-width

Comment: @AlirezaMadad im not trying to change the width.. Im trying to get rid of the input box and the not valid! in the error message.

Comment: .swal input{display:none;}